# ASDoc ignores public function definitions?

Tags: asdoc

I've got a collection of ActionScript utility functions… But when I try to run `asdoc` over them, they don't appear in the list of 'package functions'.

For example, if I run:

```
asdoc -doc-sources+=src/utils/ -doc-sources+=src/utils/map.as -doc-sources+=src/utils/max.as -source-path+="src"
```

I don't see either the `map` function or the `max` function (in fact, only one function appears):

[only one package appears http://img.skitch.com/20100202-dke3sw9bj55h6x6dc53un519su.png](http://img.skitch.com/20100202-dke3sw9bj55h6x6dc53un519su.png)

Is there any way I can coax ASDoc into showing all my public definitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in ASDoc prior to the version in the Flex 4 SDK.